# Triggering a call to a second method upon calling a first method

Tags: programming-languages, methods, language-features

Say you have method1 that contains no explicit calls to method2.

Do any programming languages support a way to call method2 when method1 is called with no modification whatsoever to the first method? If so please give a short example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), for one. It would look something like this:

```
after(): call(void method1()) {
  method2();
}
```

That is, *after* `method1` is called, execute the given code (which just calls `method2`. The whole thing is called *advice*. The `call(void method1())` part is called a *pointcut*; a pointcut is a set of *join points*---specifiable places in your program where behavior can be modified or new behavior injected. Related pointcuts and advice can be grouped into *aspects*---thus the name of the language.

There are other aspect-oriented languages with similar capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

In "[A Reflective Model for First Class Dependencies](http://www.mendeley.com/research/reflective-model-first-class-dependencies/)" the author describes a language where such dependencies can be expressed in a manner "that is orthogonal to other application concerns" with the help of meta-objects. But that was a research prototype. Research on meta-objects and meta-object protocols led to aspect-oriented programming, which made its way to industry, and which is indeed probably what would be the more realistic to use.